# Return setof varchar

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, stored-procedures, types

I have PostgreSQL table. I need in function which returns `setof varchar`. My table:

```
create table my_table (
    str varchar not null
)
```

How can I write a function that returns a set of `str` field?

Comment: have you tried `returns setof my_table.str%TYPE`?

Answer (score 1):

Basic example with `LANGUAGE SQL`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo()
  RETURNS SETOF varchar
  LANGUAGE SQL AS
$BODY$
    SELECT str
    FROM   my_table
    WHERE  <some condition>;
$BODY$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM foo();
```

Start by reading [the basics in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html).